# Ld magically overrides statically linked symbols

Tags: c++, ld, dlopen

For a few days we are dealing with very strange problem.

I can't understand how it even happens - when a third-party (MATLAB) program uses our shared library, it somehow overrides some of our symbols (boost, to be precise) with it's own. Those symbols are statically linked and (!!) local.

Here is the deal - we use boost 1.47, MATLAB has boost 1.40. Currently, library call segfaults on a call from OUR library to their boost (regex).

So, here is the magic:

- We have no library dependencies, ldd:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4abff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1a3fd65000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1a3fa51000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1a3f7cd000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f1a3f5bf000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1a3f3a8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1a3f024000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1a414f9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1a3ee1c000)
```

- No Cxx symbols (our public symbols are POC C for binary compatibility) are exported from our library, nm:

```
nm -g --defined-only libmysharedlib.so

addr1 T OurCSymbol1
addr2 T OurCSymbol2
addr3 T OurCSymbol3
...
```

- Still, it uses their boost. HOW? Stacktrace (paths cut):

```
[  0] 0x00007f21fddbb0a9 bin/libmwfl.so+00454825 fl::sysdep::linux::unwind_stack(void const**, unsigned long, unsigned long, fl::diag::thread_context const&)+000009
[  1] 0x00007f21fdd74111 bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00164113 fl::diag::stacktrace_base::capture(fl::diag::thread_context const&, unsigned long)+000161
[  2] 0x00007f21fdd7d42d bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00201773
[  3] 0x00007f21fdd7d6b4 bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so+00202420 fl::diag::terminate_log(char const*, fl::diag::thread_context const&, bool)+000100
[  4] 0x00007f21fce525a7 bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00365991
[  5] 0x00007f21fb9eb8f0 lib/libpthread.so.0+00063728
[  6] 0x00007f21f3e939a9 libboost_regex.so.1.40.0+00342441 boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_all_states()+000073
[  7] 0x00007f21f3eb6546 bin/glnxa64/libboost_regex.so.1.40.0+00484678 boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_imp()+000758
[  8] 0x00007f21c04ad595 lib/libmysharedlib.so+04855189 bool boost::regex_match, std::allocator > >, char, boost::regex_traits > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, boost::match_results, std::allocator > > >&, boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)+000245
[  9] 0x00007f21c04a71c7 lib/libmysharedlib.so+04829639 myfunc2()+000183
[ 10] 0x00007f21c01b41e3 lib/libmysharedlib.so+01737187 myfunc1()+000307
```

It's known, that MATLAB does dlopen with RTLD_NOW flag only.

People, think with me please.
Now i'm desperate not to even fix this, but to simply understand ld&elf behavior.

edit:
Small additional question: how i understood, without special linker options, symbols in linux .so libraries are never linked by address? So even statically linked local symbols are resolved in runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the `-Bsymbolic` option for **ld**.

If `-Bsymbolic` is specified, then at the time of creating a shared
object **ld** will attempt to bind references to global symbols to definitions
*within* the shared library.  The default is to defer binding to runtime.

This may be clearer with an example.

Say `example.o` contains a reference to a global function defined in
`global.o`,

```
$ nm example.o | grep ' U'
     U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
     U globalfn
$ nm global.o | grep ' T'
00000000 T globalfn
```

and two shared objects, `normal.so` and `symbolic.so`, are built as
follows:

```
$ cc -fPIC -c example.c
$ cc -c global.c
$ rm -f archive.a; ar cr archive.a global.o
$ ld -shared -o normal.so example.o archive.a
$ ld -Bsymbolic -shared -o symbolic.so example.o archive.a
```

Disassembling the code for `normal.so` shows that the call to
`globalfn` is actually going through the procedure linkage table, and
thus the final destination of the call is determined at runtime.

```
$ objdump --disassemble normal.so
...snip...
00000194 <example>:
...snip...
 1a6:   e8 d9 ff ff ff          call   184 <globalfn@plt>
...snip...
$ readelf -r normal.so

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x16c contains 1 entries:
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00001244  00000207 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   000001b8   globalfn
```

Whereas in `symbolic.so`, the call always invokes the definition of
`globalfn` within the shared object.

```
$ objdump --disassemble symbolic.so
...snip...
0000016c <shared>:
...snip...
 17e:   e8 0d 00 00 00          call   190 <globalfn>
...snip...
$ readelf -r symbolic.so

There are no relocations in this file.
```

Comment: Looks like a solution, i'll check on it )) Thx.

Immediate question - with -Bsymbolic isn't there is a possibility to override MATLAB symbols and cause "symmetric" segfault? All boost symbols in our library are 'local weak', as an info.

Comment: @ALOR `-Bsymbolic` does its work at link time, and only changes the
way "intra-object" references are resolved.  I have expanded my answer
to clarify this.

Comment: You should also consider using a linker version script to completely hide all symbols (in particular all Boost symbols) in `libmysharedlib.so`, except those that are actually required by MatLab. Doing this will speed up runtime loading of your program *and* eliminate the possibility that your library will affect some other library loaded later.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the deal - we use boost 1.47, MATLAB has boost 1.40. Currently, library call segfaults on a call from OUR library to their boost (regex).

You are invoking undefined behavior, which is a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" kind of situation. The Matlab executable already contains external functions for class `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher< elided >`. When Matlab loads your shared library the dynamic linker sees that your shared library defines those exact same symbols in a way that conflicts with the existing definitions. Undefined behavior.

The solution is to build a version of your library for use with Matlab that uses the same version of Boost as does Matlab.

Comment: I agree. However, the question is why in hell he even touches local symbols?

LD docs are quite unclear.

If i understand correctly now, without RTLD_DEEPBIND local symbols may be overrided by global ones?

Comment: What makes you think that those symbols in your shared library are "local"? At least some of them are not.

Comment: nm makes me think so :) only our public-C interface functions are global - library is compiled with -fvisibility=hidden and interface functions have gcc attribute visibility=default

Comment: @ALOR: Try using `nm -u libmysharedlib.so | c++filt`. Your function `myfunc2()` uses the template function `boost::regex_match`; it's right there in your stack trace. That small template function does its work by creating a `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher` object and then calling that object's `match` method. Eventually you are running into code that not small and it is not inlined. It is instead a part of the compiled boost library.