# Global variable defined with the same name in the so library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I wanted to know the behavior in the following scenario:-

```
//file1.c : Main file of a user-space process,say Process X.
int a; //GLobal variable in file1.c
func(); //Library function

//file2.c :Part of .so used by Process X.
int a;
void func()
{
    a=0;//Access variable a.
}
```

If the Process X calls the function `func()` of the library, what will happen?

Comment: Interesting question! Maybe this other question relates something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201667/ld-magically-overrides-statically-linked-symbols , for functions, though. As I read through some man pages (ld.so, dlopen), it seems variables may be handled differently, but I am no expert on this. Also waiting for a nice answer!

Comment: You understood the question right..:)..I am looking for something similar on global variables

Answer (score 2):

In `file1.c` you have defined

```
int a;
```

which tells the compiler to allocate memory for `a` in that compilation unit, an all references to `a` will be resolved there by the *compiler* (and *not* the linker). So `file1` sees its own `a` and `file1` sees its own `a`. If you had instead, used

```
extern int a;
```

in `file1` then the compiler will defer resolution of this symbol to the linker, and then  `a` will be resolved outside of `file2.c`.

Since `file2` is a shared object, *if* variable `a` is supposed to be used by other files, then `file2.so` would likely come with a `file2.h`, which would have the line

```
extern int a;
```

and this `file2.h` would then be `#include`d in `file1.c`.

Comment: file2.c is a shared object,linked and loaded dynamically to Process X.

Comment: "Since file2 is a shared object, if variable a is supposed to be used by other files, then file2.so would likely come with a file2.h, which would have the line"  No. You're not getting the point..the other file is calling the function func() which accesses variable a.there is no need of externing the variable in the header file.The header file will just carry the prototype of func().

Comment: no need to claim `extern`. it makes no difference between you claim it or not since `extern` is default state.

Answer (score 0):

have a test. so easy.

a in file2 is linked with func, so a in file1 won't be affected. they are different two variables.

Comment: Note that both are "extern Global" variables.and file2.c is a shared lib

Comment: @NeelanshMittal that's what i am talking about. a in file2 won't be "dynamically" linked to a in file1 in this case.

Comment: File2 is part of a shared object(dynamic lib)..it has to be linked dynimically

Comment: i was wrong. here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam btw, variables in C is extern by default.

Comment: From the above link;" Again, ODR applies across the board: an extern global variable will be shared across modules, meaning that it should have only one definition across all the modules loaded.". That's my question,I have broken this rule in my scenario,now Wat will happen

Comment: that means you will get `0` if X references to `a` directly. they are the same variable.

Comment: X is not accessing directly,it is accessing via function func()

Comment: where is function x now... any way, they are the same. they are the same variable having the same name located in the same address. no matter it's static or dynamic linking, they will be the same variable eventually.